# Doctrine Symfony2 persist association entity with existing one

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have two entities Product and Category with association of type ManyToOne, Supposed i want to create a new Product and i already know its category (means i know ID category)

CLASS PRODUCT

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Category")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $category;
}
```

CLASS CATEGORY

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="category")
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

SCRNARIO: creat new product and supposed i know the ID category so we dont need to use the find method of Category Entity to get it (making things faster)

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$category = new Category();
$category->setId(12);
$product = new Product();
$product->setName('product 1');
$product->setCategory($category);
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

the code above is not working it generate an exception:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
>   'AOBundle\Entity\Product#category' that was not configured to cascade
>   persist operations for entity:
>   AOBundle\Entity\Category@0000000049a05dc500000000723a1be6. To solve
>   this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this
>   unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the
>   mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot
>   find out which entity causes the problem implement
>   'AOBundle\Entity\Category#__toString()' to get a clue.

but when i use the find method to get the category instance it worked, but i don't like this solution i want to make the application faster is there any solution.
Thanks

Comment: The clean way would be to fetch the entity (for example using `->find(12)` - I don't know why you would go to such lengths to avoid that... You could *try* `$category = $em->merge($category);` after your `$category->setId(12);` call.

Comment: Lookup Doctrine references which avoids the need to actually load an entity.  $category = $em->getReference(12);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use EntityManager's getReference method for this.

Your code should look like this.

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
$category = $em->getReference('AppBundle:Category', 12);

$product = new Product();
$product->setName('product 1');
$product->setCategory($category);

$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: that's what i need get a object of category without going to database. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, my solution was to avoid storing the category to a variable, but always call the find function. I haven't found an explanation for it, but it helped me to move ahead. In your example:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$category = new Category();
$category->setId(12);
$em->persist($category);

$product = new Product();
$product->setName('product 1');
$product->setCategory($em->getRepository(Category::class)->find(12));
$em->persist($product);

$product = new Product();
$product->setName('product 2');
$product->setCategory($em->getRepository(Category::class)->find(12));
$em->persist($product);

$em->flush();
```

Answer (score -1):

The error means that if you persist product you need to use cascade because you haven't already create the category.

So you can do something like this:

```
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
$category = new Category();
$category->setId(12);
$em->persist($category);

$product = new Product();
$product->setName('product 1');
$product->setCategory($category);
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

I don't know why you set the category Id but I advise you to remove It

Comment: the category with the ID 12 is already in the database so why i would create another one, it is a violation primary constraint